# GCM pass variable and do something

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

The application I am developing can recieve a notification with Google Cloud Messaging.
But now I wonder if it is possible to send variables from the PHP code, and handle them in the background to execute a function?

I also like to know if I can do something with a variable that is send with the notification once the notification has been clicked by the user.

I have been searching for an example, but I can't find one with Google Cloud Messaging.
Maybe I'm not using the right keywords/tags to find it.

I am sorry to ask this kind of question here, it will probably be as simple as finding the right thing to look for, and so finding an code/project example.

Comment: Kindle go to this example [http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) in this demo user can send some Text from server and `Receive` into `onMessage(.....)`  method in `GCMIntentService` and then generate a `Notification`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The androidhive tutorial uses the deprecated method of handling GCM, its GCMIntentService is part of the package **com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService**. The newer method of dealing with GCM uses the PlayServices API and its GCMIntentService is part of the package **com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging**.

***However***, whichever method is used in the client, you end up checking an intent for extras to extract the elements of the message (in onMessage() for the old way and in onHandleIntent() for the newer method). The PHP server side stays the same.

If you were passing in a message on this little php example with

*someurl/example.php?message=this is a message*

```
<?php session_start();
   require 'vals.php';
   $randomNum=rand(10,100);
   $registrationIDs[] = $regidOne;
   $message =  $_GET['message'];
   $morestuff = 'More text for you';

   $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
   $fields = array(
           'registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,
             'data' => array( "message" => $message,
                              "moredata" => $morestuff),
             'delay_while_idle'=> false,
             'time_to_live' => 86400,
             'collapse_key'=>"".$randomNum.""
            );
   $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
         'Content-Type: application/json'
         );

   // Open connection
   $ch = curl_init();

   // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
   curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
   curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
   curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ));

   // Execute post
   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   // Close connection
   curl_close($ch);
   echo "Your message has been sent, the results from the Cloud Server were :\n$
   echo "<p>";
   echo $result;
?>
```

Then you would pick out the message on the client side with:

```
if (intent.hasExtra("message")) {
  String theMessage = intent.getStringExtra("message");
  //do something
}
```

and deal with your required extra data with :

```
if (intent.hasExtra("moredata")) {
  String moreData = intent.getStringExtra("moredata");
  //do something else
}
```

Typically the 'do something' could be to start an Activity.