# how make android notification pointing specific web-link

Tags: php, android

I am developing an Android web-App.

I use on server side PHP to send the notification

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$fcmUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fcmNotification));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

and all works fine.

The Problem is that when on the phone I click on the notification, it always open the main page "www.mywebsite.com/index.php".

Is there a way to send with php a particular URL (example "www.mywebsite.com/product.php?product_id=123") so when the notification is clicked, the selected product page is displayed ?

Comment: You need to add the final URL as additional `data` to your post field and then get the information back in Java with `Intent.getExtras()` Here's the Java part: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53125781/1529324

Comment: ok thanks. do you have a better tutorial ? the link contains only a bit of code with no explanation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GCM pass variable and do something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22347737/gcm-pass-variable-and-do-something)

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` why are you doing this?  That seems dangerous.

Comment: the code curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); actually comes from the suggested answer "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22347737/gcm-pass-variable-and-do-something"